# C# Serving a stream to a browser - can it be done?

Tags: c#, file, rest, streaming

I am trying to output a file to the browser from a REST API - but I don't have a physical file, instead I have a MemoryStream (and I would prefer not to write a physical file).

This works:

```
HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
return result;
```

This does not:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();

// Iterate DataReader and populate MemoryStream code omitted for brevity.
// Assume MemoryStream has been written to correctly and contains data.

HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
return result;
```

This has consumed most of my weekend so I would be delighted if anyone can offer some definitive insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer through trial and error and a lot of research:

Yes, it can be done.

Instead of using StreamContent use ByteArrayContent:
e.g.

```
result.Content = new ByteArrayContent( stream.GetBuffer() );
```

**Ensure that there is no HttpResponseMessage.ContentLength set or it will fail to work (connection reset) - it took me hours to figure that out.**

Comment: What are you doing with result to open that on a browser?